# list all subfolders in a directory and written on to a text file

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-listing

I need to list all subfolders in a directory and written on to text file.But when i coded only the last subfolder is only written on to the file.Please help.I am a beginner to Java.

```
public class Main {
//    private Object bufferedWriter;

    /**
     * Prints some data to a file using a BufferedWriter
     */
    public void writeToFile(String filename) {
         try
        {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));


        int i=1;
        File f=new File("D:/Moviezzz");
        File[] fi=f.listFiles();
        for(File fil:fi)
        {
            if(fil.isHidden())
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }    
            else if(fil.isDirectory()||fil.isFile())
            {
               int s=i++;

               String files = fil.getName();



            //Start writing to the output stream
            bufferedWriter.write(s+" "+fil);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

           // bufferedWriter.write(s+" "+files);
            }

        }


            //Construct the BufferedWriter object


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();}

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().writeToFile("d://my.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try closing the `BufferedWriter` after the loop.

Comment: have you did flush()? Try it.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, you are right, you should post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uptil you call `flush()` method of BufferWriter class it will not write your data to file.

It is not necessary to flush() every time in a loop. But you can write it after your end of the loop.

Main thing to put that `yourObj.flush()` is to keep your buffer memory clean. as after call of that flush() method, data will be release from memory and written to your file.

Comment: how to list all folders in a directory without changing order even when new files are added,in a file using JAVA with Sql server2008 @Pietu1998,@Ketan

Answer (score 0):

Close the `BufferedReader` after the loop.

```
for(File fil:fi)
{
    ...
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

Also, I suggest these changes in your code to make it more readable and efficient:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
...
if(!fil.isHidden() && (fil.isDirectory() || fil.isFile()))
{
    ...
}
```

You can create the `BufferedReader`directly. Then, you are getting the file name, but not doing anything with it, so just remove the get. And last, you don't have to have put `System.out.print("");` in an `if` to check if the file is hidden. You can use an empty statement or even no code, or use the `!` operator to invert.

```
if(fil.isHidden())
{
    ; // Do nothing
}
else
{
    // Do something
}

if(fil.isHidden()); // Do nothing
else
{
    // Do something
}

if(!fil.isHidden)
{
    // Do something
}
```